# I am getting oci usage data using the SDK and storing in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mern, react-fullstack

I am getting OCI usage data with the help of sdk and storing the MongoDB getting this issue please find this issue

> Error while storing data in MongoDB: documents must be a non-empty list

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you add some code to this question (in a code block and not an image) to show readers how you are storing a document?